# How do I list all 'Urgent' priority bugs across all projects in Redmine?

Tags: migration, workflow, redmine, bugzilla

We're migrating from Bugzilla to Redmine and there's one feature of bugzilla which I'm unsure how to replicate in Redmine.

Is there any way to list all the bugs / features of a specific priority across all projects?

We used to use this mechanism to identify what bugs / features to assign next to developers. If listing all urgent bugs doesn't work in Redmine, perhaps there's a different way of working which could be used instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy:

- Go to https://your.redmine.domain/issues?set_filter=1 : This should clear any current filter criteria and display all open issues across all projects the currently logged user has access to.
- Select your filter - in this case, add a filter for `Priority`, and hit apply
- You may [save this filter](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineIssueList#Applying-and-saving-filters) by clicking on `Save`: This will allow you to access to this filter quickly without configuring it every time. You may also choose grouping criteria as well as the columns to display.